# JBOSS SQL Logging

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, logging, jboss

Using JBOSS

I would like to see the query being executed in the logs - and I need to see it in a plain SQL, (if possible).
For example, I have a DO class with the named query

```
@NamedQuery(name="MyElementDO.findByAllStuff",
  query="SELECT o FROM MyElementDO o WHERE <here goes some list of 
   conditions>")
@Table(name = "tblElement")
public class MyElementDO implements Serializable      
{
  //all mapped fields
}
```

In my EJB class, I am calling this by

```
Query qry =manager.createNamedQuery("MyElementDO.findByAllStuff").
            setParameter("param1", value1).<some more setParameters() 
             >...setParameter("param_n", vaue_n);
    list =  qry.getResultList() ;
```

The problem is that when I designed this query and am running it in SQL Server management studio, I get 3 records back (which is OK)
When the Java EJB class executes it, I get 1 record back.
The actual query is very large, with a lot of parameters, some of which are set based on conditions.  I would like to see the actual query being executed by JBOSS Jvm.  So, my question is:
How can I enable the log?
I did this - set loging categories in jBoss console, like found here
[HERE](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html), on this page

However, I get a very unclear to me output, like this

```
\-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
+-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
|  +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
|  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
|  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
|  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
|  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
|  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
|  |     |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
|  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'package'
|  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'subpackage'
|  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'entity'
|  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'MyElementDO'
|  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'o'
|  \-[SELECT] Node: 'SELECT'
|     \-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
\-[WHERE] Node: 'WHERE'
   \-[EQ] Node: '='
      +-[DOT] Node: '.'
      |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
      |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
      |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'RelatedTableDO'
      |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'someId'
      \-[COLON] Node: ':'
         \-[IDENT] Node: 'strPlanId'
```

and, I guess, I can sit and translate it into a regular syntax, but can I get a normal translated SQL output?

Comment: I find that the most helpful logging settings for this are setting `org.hibernate.SQL` to `DEBUG` and setting `org.hibernate.type` to `TRACE`

Comment: I added them.  Either I do not understand the output in the log files, or it is not the output I am looking for.
When I have the same thing running in WEBLOGIC, I can see the clear output of a query, using HQL format.  So I can't use it directly in Query analyzer, but i can easily translate  it.  I want to see something similar in Jboss...